# Grails 3: Constraint pattern to validate at least 1 field is NOT NULL

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

I have a command object that get populated via Search form and I want to validate that at least 1 field was submitted.  Currently I am doing the validation in the Controller and looping through all the properties.

```
class SearchCommand implements Validateable {
    List<String> termID;
    List<String> subject;
    List<String> title;
}

def getSearch(SearchCommand cmd) {
        boolean isFormEmpty = true;

        //make sure at least 1 property is filled out.
        SearchCommand.metaClass.properties.each{ MetaProperty prop ->
            if(prop.field && cmd[prop.name] && !cmd[prop.name].isEmpty()) {
                isFormEmpty = false;
            }
        }
}
```

So this works but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.  I would prefer to have this built into the command object so I can just call `cmd.hasErrors()`.  Not sure if there is a clean & non-hacky way to do this that is dynamic to where when I add/remove properties I don't have to change the validation logic.

Comment: Yes, you can and should put validation logic into `constraints`

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/validation.html